# identify highest value of several variables of one agent

Tags: netlogo

I have an agent that has 3 variables quantifying the area required for certain tasks as calculated by other agents. The agent has another variable "max_area", and in each tick, this should be given the maximal value.

e.g the agent has the variables 
area_cattle: 100
area_gather: 200
area_fields: 300

tick

area_cattle: 200
area_gather: 500
area_fields: 200

and i want it to set its variable max_area to 300, then in the next tick to 500.

any ideas?

many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can built a list out of the values in your three variables and use [`max`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#max) on that list:

```
set max_area max (list area_cattle area_gather area_fields)
```